# Can't send email from PHP with SSMTP

Tags: apache2, php, email

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7. I make a website that allows admin to send an email to other admin. So I installed SSMTP and configured it properly. Here is the thing :

1. I can send an email by using terminal with this code :

   ```
   sudo ssmtp myother@gmail.com
   ```
2. I can send an email by using PHP but from terminal. So I use this

   ```
   php index.php
   ```

but I can't send an email from browser (by going to localhost/sendemail). What's the problem ?

note : I've changed this in php.ini :

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
```

Comment: In the first example there is `sudo` command, do you need root privileges  also for the second one? If that is the case maybe you need to grand sudo privileges to `www-data` for this command. Use `sudo visudo` and add this line: `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ssmtp`.

Comment: Yes, in the second one I should use sudo too. And it's still not working tough..